# Mosaico mailings not sending

Tags: civimail, mosaico, shoreditch, flexmailer

We've updated our CiviCRM to version 5.2.2 and Mosaico to version 2.0 beta 4 and since then we are not able to send any mailing from CiviCRM.

To be clear we can mail to a person individually. Because we are hosting our website on a VPS I was able to check the email log. I noticed that emails (to one person) are going out correctly, but when I try to send a mailing I get something like this "The sender address  is not a valid 553 5.1.2 RFC-5321 address.". Sometimes the from address is empty.

I'm hosting on a Plesk server 17.5.2 with PHP 7.1.

Is there someone who has idea's for a solution?

**EDIT:**
Jul  6 11:24:11 srv1 postfix/pickup[15216]: B363D8F4B73: uid=10006 from=
Jul  6 11:24:11 srv1 postfix/cleanup[19523]: B363D8F4B73: message-id=<20180706092411.B363D8F4B73@shost.tld>
Jul  6 11:24:11 srv1 postfix/qmgr[15217]: B363D8F4B73: from=, size=89808, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  6 11:24:11 srv1 postfix/smtp[19542]: B363D8F4B73: to="", relay=aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c04::1b]:25, delay=0.09, delays=0.01/0/0.07/0.01, dsn=5.1.2, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c04::1b] said: 553-5.1.2 The sender address  is not a valid 553 5.1.2 RFC-5321 address. u42-v6si5509030edm.404 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of your mail account setting for bounce processing?  **Administer menu » CiviMail » Mail Accounts**, then **Edit** next to your bounce account.

Comment: We are using the PHP mail() service to deliver emails. And the mail accounts only for incoming mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that didn't set up a bouncing email account. Weird because it worked before without it... But anyway that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments, I believe I see the issue.

CiviMail requires bounce processing to be enabled to work properly.  The [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/) might want to emphasize this point - but your error is actually mentioned in the [VERP Support](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#verp-support) section.

VERP is a standard by which you send each email from a different "From" address - so when a server responds that the recipient address is no good, you know exactly which email triggered the problem.  CiviMail determines the VERP address in part by the bounce processing address.  With no bounce processing address, you get the "invalid sender address" either.  You can solve this by configuring a bounce processing address.

**EDIT**

logs:

```
Jul  6 11:24:11 srv1 postfix/pickup[15216]: B363D8F4B73: uid=10006 from=<b.2999.15367.c7a49eeef87f384f@>
Jul  6 11:24:11 srv1 postfix/cleanup[19523]: B363D8F4B73: message-id=<20180706092411.B363D8F4B73@shost.tld>
Jul  6 11:24:11 srv1 postfix/qmgr[15217]: B363D8F4B73: from=<b.2999.15367.c7a49eeef87f384f@>, size=89808, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  6 11:24:11 srv1 postfix/smtp[19542]: B363D8F4B73: to="<emailaddress>", relay=aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c04::1b]:25, delay=0.09, delays=0.01/0/0.07/0.01, dsn=5.1.2, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c04::1b] said: 553-5.1.2 The sender address <b.2999.15367.c7a49eeef87f384f@> is not a valid 553 5.1.2 RFC-5321 address. u42-v6si5509030edm.404 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

Comment: I checked the VERP settings but it doesn't change much. I can disable it or enable it, it still gives the same error in the maillog.

Comment: Now that i take a second look at the logs, i notice that the domain is missing from the "from" parameter.